# Firebase.setString() not working (esp8266 wifi module)

Tags: firebase, esp8266, arduino-ide

I'm a beginner and I was trying to send and receive data from firebase by using the esp8266 wifi module, but it didn't seem to work, nor did it return any error, please solve this issue

This is my code :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

// Set these to run example.
#define FIREBASE_HOST "esp8266-d2343-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "THE_API_KEY_OF_MY_DATABASE"
#define WIFI_SSID "Lenovo Tab 3211"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "MY_WIFI_PASSWORD"
                                           
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);    
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);                 
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);                               
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);       
  Firebase.setString("LED_STATUS", "OFF");                
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(Firebase.getString("LED_STATUS))l
}
```

It's not a problem if there's anything wrong in the **void loop()** code, I just typed it as an example,but please let me know if you find anything else in the code

I have also update the FirebaseFingerPrint to this :

CF:6C:F8:33:A3:FB:42:4A:49:0A:E7:72:24:53:1A:11:A2:C1:34:0D // 2022-APRIL

I didn't find anything newer than this one

Comment: Forgot to mention this, I'm using realtime database for this project

Comment: I don't see any reference to `FirebaseFingerPrint` in the code you posted. Could you please edit the question to post the code you are actually running? It's fine to replace sensitive information in it like you did, but posting code that you didn't actually run and that doesn't compile and is missing important things isn't helpful. When you build your program are there any warnings? Also, the Firebase library (at least the one I'm looking at) has methods for `success()` and `failed()` that you should call after operations to check if the library thinks they worked.

Comment: I was actually running some source code from a YouTube tutorial, but then I replaced it with the code you see above, there are some warnings:


`esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/cu.usbserial-A50285BI
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: e8:db:84:e1:60:c3
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Compressed 365584 bytes to 266105..`
But these just appear every time and then the upload starts

Comment: The firebase fingerprint gets updated every once in a while (as per what I've observed), whenever it updates, we need to change it from the `FirebaseHTTPClient.h` file , so I wanted to know if it was the latest fingerprint

Comment: I found the answer, the firebase fingerprint just got updated today this is the link to the pull request in case of reference
[link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/pull/546/files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FirebaseFingerPrint` just updated to this :
***5A:80:FB:80:F8:CD:DF:B4:C0:22:15:C6:42:DF:88:9A:F3:C9:39:75***

So, I just needed to change it in the `FirebaseHttpClient.h` file and it started to work